# How can I split a single visual studio project into multiple projects?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

Right now I have a single ASP.NET solution with one project in it.  The problem I'm facing is that multiple developers are working on different parts of the project that are getting released at different times.  Because of this my project manager is thinking we can split the project into multiple dlls instead of just one dll so that we can update just the modules that need to updated.

**1. Is splitting the project into multiple projects (multiple dlls) the correct way to solve this problem?**

**2. If so, how do I do this?**
Can I just copy the appropriate aspx/cs files to the new project, remove them from the old one and build?  What about Master Pages, CSS, Javascript and User-Controls, will I need to copy those along as well or can they be referenced in the "Core" Project?  Would I need to make some adjustments in IIS or can I just copy the aspx from the new "sub-project" to the root of the "Core" Project (essentially where the aspx files are now)?

**3. If not, what is the better solution to fix my issue?**

Thanks for your help

*Edit (to add a bit more clarity):*

Right now our structure is something like this (shortened and code-behind implied):

```
MasterPage.master
styles.css
SplashPage.aspx
Page.aspx    
AnotherPage.aspx
a_MasterPage.master
a_Page.aspx
a_AnotherPage.aspx
b_Page.aspx
b_AnotherPage.aspx
b_AlsoAnotherPage.aspx
```

Can I take all the `a_` pages and roll them into one project and all the `b_` pages and roll them into another (which would separate the dlls).

If this doesn't make sense please ask and I'll try to explain it better

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes
2. How? Don't think in terms of pages, but rather functionality. The best way to handle your issue is to move the business logic out of the ASP.NET experience layer project and put it in class libraries. You can then have different types of developers working on different types of code.

Now, if you truly have different "sites", meaning they serve different purposes, then you may have to move some pages to one and other pages to another. I can't answer whether that is a need or not.

Hopefully, this all makes sense. NOTE: If you code is contained in Page_Load() and event handlers, you are pretty much screwed until you can refactor the code into individual methods.

Answer (score 1):

3.) What about some version control system, wouldn't that serve you better?

Splitting project like this isn't a good idea imo, it would make sense, if you would like to split logical/physical layers of that project (you could have different project for your data access, another for business logic etc.) But splitting to projects, where one contains "welcome.aspx" and second one "contact.aspx".. hmm I would rather use SVN / Git / TFS / Whatever ;)

Comment: (by Yoeri) note: they plan to release their different modules on different times, so SVN isn't really rhe issue I'm guessing. (sorry didn't find another way to comment)

Comment: Question is: What is a 'module' in their project? If it's a page, why svn wouldn't help with that? Team, working on that will just commmit last working version of their files and then they can build and relase any part from that.

Comment: A module is just a new page (or several).

Comment: @Daniel: Then I don't see, why 'SVN' wouldn't be enough. You can do things like branches and merging. I would vote for SVN for simple project structure like this. Splitting files here doesn't make any sense to me so far ;)

Comment: @Dampe Thanks for your response. (We are using VSS) The problem I have noticed with this is that if another developer adds a new file they checkout the whole project and then it somehow "Gets Latest" on my machine. This causes me to get their last checked in changes and then those end up in the wrong release.  Is this possibly a configuration issue?

Comment: Yes, I believe you will probably need to come with working structure of branches, which you will then merge into specific versions. So you might have something like branch A (you are wokrking on this one) and branch B (theirs).. each of you use specific branch (so when they commit to B, you won't get it at A) and when release time comes, you will merge those two branches into some "release branch" and do build/relase from it. I am not the one, who does this at our team, but it works like this afaik.

Comment: Oh I again merged them together. Of course that you could make realease just from A or B :)

Comment: 1999 called, they want their source control back. VSS? Seriously? Switch to git or similar so you can easily get each dev on their own branch. 0_o

Answer (score 1):

Normally you split the project according to the function or feature eg. you could split off the data access layer into a different project.

I ussually try to keep my view together and separate the core features, so it would be easy to use the same dll's over different websites.

eg: I have a project with all the methods and a db for user management.
I could deploy this project on a server and reference it in all my websites.
This way users can use the same login over all my websites.

So once you have a core system, everyone can make his own project and just reference the projects needed.

Yes you just move your aspx/c# files to a different project and reference the new project in your existing project.

I do think that every project needs his own masterpage though (last time I checked that is).

I hope this answers you question.